# Unable to get correct offset of floated div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div id="content">
<div class="oddpost">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
    <div class="oddpost">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
    <div class="oddpost">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
    <div class="oddpost">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

```javascript
$(function() {
    if (($(".oddpost").position().left + $(".oddpost").width()) >= $("#content").width()) {
        $('.arrow').hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ek5Gy/52/

In the code, I have a div(`.arrow`) nested on another div(`.oddpost`). What I want to do is hide the `.arrow` of the left `.oddpost` only. The idea is `.arrow` hides when `.oddpost` is near the left side of `#content`.

I've tried using offset but it gives the same `offset().left` value on all the oddpost div so all the arrow div still hides, even the one on the right.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I dont follow the question, im sorry. Is you fiddle wrong? As there are two boxes on the left

Comment: @Adrengski: I edited the code in because questions on Stack Overflow should not rely on linking off-site to make sense.  jsFiddle, in particular, has a poor track record for up time and viewers will only be confused if they are unable to access it.  I will restore my edit now that I have given you the reason for it, please do not undo it again.

Comment: @andyE Thanks, I didn't know that, and I thought Stack Overflow was just acting up since I didn't post that part up. SO sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) call returns values for the first selected element (it doesn't work on all selected elements as many other jQuery calls). Check Javadoc.

This is working for me:

```
$(function(){

    $(".oddpost").each (function (idx, el) {  
        if ($(el).position().left < $(el).width()) {
            $('.arrow', el).hide();
        }
    });

});
```

The modified jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ek5Gy/54/

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem lies in your selector usage:

```
// selecting stuff
$(".oddpost")

// doing stuff on the selection
.position().left
```

But, you'll have to know how those helper methods work on the given set. [`position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) (and many others) will only work on the very first element in the set. Not on every element.

So what you have to do is, [iterate](http://api.jquery.com/each/) over each element in the set and do the test for every element independently, like:

```
$(".oddpost").each(function () {
  if ($(this).prev().length === 0 || $(this).offset().left < $(this).prev().offset().left) {
     $('.arrow', this).hide();
  }
});

// or
$(".oddpost").each(function () {
  if ($(this).position().left === 0) {
    $('.arrow', this).hide();
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ek5Gy/53/

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine.

In your example the value of:

`$(".oddpost").position().left + $(".oddpost").width() // Equals 100`

This is less the total of #content which is 270px. Your asking if it's greater than or equal too. If you want to hide the arrow when it's near the left try this:

```
 if ($(".oddpost").position().left === 0) {
     $('.arrow').hide();
 }
```

EDIT:

```
$(function(){

$(".oddpost").each(function(){

    var position = $(this).position().left;
    alert (position);

    if(position === 0){
       // Do what you need to here.
    }

});
```

});

This is what your looking for...

Comment: This still hides all of the .arrow. Even the one that is on the right part of #content. Is there any way to hide just the ones on the left? I noticed floated divs still give the same position or offset even if they are on the right.

Comment: @BennyC - Always use `===` to compare with '0'

Comment: My bad... Was rushing to get it on! Thanks for the edit though.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `$('.arrow').hide()` will always act on all DOM elements that match that particular selector (`.arrow`). Also, your calculations are only performed once, for the first `.oddpost` element, since that's the behavior of the `position()` jQuery function.

I just did not follow exactly what you meant by "near the left of content". I've altered your code a bit to reflect all these changes and prepared a little jsFiddle. Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ek5Gy/56/).

Comment: @Yoshi - I've edited the answer so that it reflects what the link was all about. Thanks.